# Looking for a mobile platform to view vector data and use it like a simple map

Tags: android, ios, vector-graphics

I would like to develop or use an existing platform that will allow me to view custom vector data and use it as a map on mobile phones such as Android/IPhone (Maybe even WP7).

I'm hoping that there's already a good infrastructure for what I need so I would not need to develop a whole infrastructure by myself.

In Conclusion -

1. Is there any existing platform that may answer my needs?
2. If not, how would you guys suggest I should begin? How should I save my vector data? How could I read it? Should I view it with a graphics engine like OpenGL? Is there any chance this solution could be cross-platform?

I know that it's possible since it was already done with apps like [Waze](http://www.waze.com/). And it works the same on iOS and Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I found a solution that fits most of my needs.
At the moment I decided to go on Android only so I'm using AndEngine (In the future I guess it would be pure OpenGL).
AndEngine can read .svg files and turn them into PNGs at runtime, and also has a built in support for ZoomCamera which allows me to pan and zoom the map very easily.

I'm converting the SVG to PNG because apparently mobile devices do not have a very good anti-aliasing support, and rendering curved paths can also be a problem.